# How can a Diesel motor be drawn on a $pV$-diagram?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, volume

Only quasi-static processes can be drawn on a PV-diagram, because during a quasi-static process thermodyanamic variables such as pressure $p$ and volume $V$ are well-defined. However, for example, the Diesel-motor works by adiabatically compressing air very quickly, which is obviously not quasi-static.

How can we define the cycle of a Diesel motor on a PV-diagram then?

Answer (score 1):

One proceeds by a sequence of approximations.

The first, most rough, approach, is to say that each stage is quasistatic for the working fluid as a whole. This is good enough to get a rough estimate of the amounts of heat and work and the overall efficiency.

The next stage is to divide the working fluid up into many small cells. The relaxation time (time to reach thermal equilibrium) for a small cell goes down with the size of the cell. The thermal relaxation time of a sphere of radius $R$ is approximately
$$
\tau = \frac{R^2}{\pi^2 D}
$$
where $D = \kappa/c$ is the thermal diffusion coefficient. For an ideal gas $D \simeq \lambda \bar{v}$ where $\lambda$ is the mean free path, so
$$
\frac{\tau_r}{\tau_c} \simeq \frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{R}{\lambda} \right)^2
$$
where $\tau_c$ is the collision time ($\lambda/\bar{v}$).

The relaxation time of a cell of gas of diameter 10 microns is about 100 nanoseconds at standard temperature and pressure. Such a cell is still large enough to allow thermodynamic concepts to apply. Hence the behaviour of each such cell can be said to be quasistatic for processes whose timescale is microseconds or more.

The overall result is that reasoning based on quasistatic processes can be applied, as long as one has enough computing resources to model the working fluid on a small scale. For the very fast processes involved in the explosive chemical reactions, one requires a different kind of modelling, but nevertheless the net result can then be incorporated into thermodynamic reasoning applied to the outcome of these processes.